# Why does this install file not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a news script and the install file doesn't add any SQL data to my database.

This is [the code](http://alamuae.com/lessons/images/web/mynews.zip) and I assure you that the config file is good, with no errors in it.

Comment: Please ask a proper question, telling us what doesn't work. Throwing a ton of code into people's faces is rude.

Comment: What errors do you get in your php, webserver, and mysqld logs?

Comment: First of all, try to use `<?php` + `?>` PHP tags, it's supported better than `<?`

Comment: Don't point us to download any files, you should post your problem code right here.

Comment: @magy "doesn't work" is not an error description. Please try to specify what exactly doesn't work, and what errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive any errors and take appropriate action on that. Make sure that you put these lines on top of your script to see any errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also instead of:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

Use:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

to see if there are any errors in the query itself.

Finally try using full php tags `<?php ... ?>` instead of `<? ... ?>` because chances are that short tags are disabled on your server.